# raw_input in subprocess using python

Tags: python

I've a problem with shell command, when i want to enter a value by using raw_input and put it in shell command, it displays "s was unexpected in this context".
Here is my program:

```
import curses, sys, os, signal,argparse
from multiprocessing import Process
from scapy.all import *
from subprocess import call, PIPE

def main():


   var=raw_input("Entre wap's @mac: ")

   subprocess.call('tshark -r crackWEP.pcap "((wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x20)&&(wlan.bssid==**"%s"%var**))"|wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if __name__ == u'__main__':  
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not substituting `var` in the command now, are you?

You mixed `bash` and `python`. You probably meant:

```
var=raw_input("Entre wap's @mac: ")
subprocess.call('tshark -r crackWEP.pcap "((wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x20)&&(wlan.bssid==**"%s"%'+var+'**))"|wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Also care with user input and `shell=True`. People like to put "*much fun*" in there. I'd advise to call `tshark`, with `shell=False`, catch output from it and count lines in python. Running separate external program seems like a waste.

Edit:

2nd more pythonic version:

```
   command = 'tshark -r crackWEP.pcap "((wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x20)&&(wlan.bssid==**"%s"%{}**))"|wc -l'.format(var)
   subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: `+` with strings is a bad practice in Python. Use `.format()` instead, or the `%` operator if you prefer C-style formatting.

Comment: @Grapsus I work on python3 and personally use format all the time, but I am not sure if 2.7 supports it. Does it?

Comment: It does, since python 2.6 when pep-3101 came out.

Comment: @Grapsus Well, it is less readable to me in this spaghetti so I posted it as an alternative.

Comment: I tried the two solutions but it displays error: tshark: "*" was unexpected in this context.